# TypeError: not expecting type '<type 'bytes'>' on ironpython package install

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, ironpython

I'm trying to install some packages for IronPython 2.7 using this command:

```
>C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\> ipy -X:Frames -m pip install (PackageName)
```

And I keep getting these blocks of error messages.

```
>ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 185, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 332, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 179, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 362, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 305, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    skip_reason = self._check_skip_installed(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\legacy\resolver.py", line 250, in _check_skip_installed
    self.finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 900, in find_requirement
    best_candidate_result = self.find_best_candidate(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 883, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 827, in find_all_candidates
    package_links = self.process_project_url(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 792, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 612, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 451, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 149, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 421, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 314, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\models.py", line 380, in prepare_url
    scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\url.py", line 381, in parse_url
    host = _normalize_host(host, scheme)
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\url.py", line 296, in _normalize_host
    return six.ensure_str(
  File "C:\Program Files\IronPython 2.7\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 951, in ensure_str
    raise TypeError("not expecting type '%s'" % type(s))
TypeError: not expecting type '<type 'bytes'>'
```

I have no idea what any of this means. I'm totally stumped.

This is happening as I'm trying to pythonnet to IronPython for Visual Studio. Pip works fine for me on standard Python but this is only happening to me with IronPython.

What do they mean? What's wrong here? How do I fix this?

PS: This is happening on my Windows 10 laptop.

Comment: Did you solve this problem already? I'm facing it aswell.

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem following this question:
[Why does IronPython tell me that pip is a package and not an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432275/why-does-ironpython-tell-me-that-pip-is-a-package-and-not-an-executable)

Probably you upgraded the IronPython pip as I did.

1. Remove anything regarding pip and setuptools in Lib/site-packages
2. Run `ipy -X:Frames -m ensurepip`

Now you should be able to install through pip.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverview! Thanks for contributing by posting an answer.